# Dataset R eliminate columns with mean 0 for correlation

Tags: r, powerbi

I have a dataset in R, which I want correlation with `pairs()`.
The dataset includes columns with total 0. This way is necessary, so the process is more flexible.

How can I exclude before the `pairs()` the column with total mean zero?

data looks like

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
0   1   2   0
0   2   3   0
0   2   3   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
 mean_is_0 <- sapply(my_data, mean) == 0
 my_data <- my_data[ ! mean_is_0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **dplyr**:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'x1  x2  x3  x4
0   1   2   0
                 0   2   3   0
                 0   2   3   0', header = T)

library(dplyr)
df <- select_if(df, .predicate = function(x) mean(x) != 0)

  x2 x3
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  3
```